# Why do we look for the shortest augmenting path in the Hopcroft-Karp algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, matching

In the Hopcroft-Karp algorithm for maximum bipartite matching, why do we always look for the shortest augmenting path in the breadth first search?  Is it because the breadth first search always finds the shortest path?  I'm just confused why it's important for the augmenting path to be the shortest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding just one augmenting path is already a Theta(|E|)-time operation. The idea behind Hopcroft–Karp (most augmenting-path algorithms, really, if one squints a bit) is to do more with each Theta(|E|)-time iteration.

Why shortest augmenting paths? H–K looks for several augmenting paths at once, which must be vertex-disjoint to be useful simultaneously. The vertex-disjointness creates a packing problem, to which the greedy solution is to pack the "densest" (best value to space ratio) things first, i.e., the shortest augmenting paths. In practice, greedy algorithms often work well (see, for example, the analyses of set cover, or H–K on random graphs).

The real answer, though, is that H–K is provably better than Theta(|E| |V|). The formal analysis of H–K uses the length of a shortest augmenting path to measure the progress of the algorithm, and by using a maximal set of these paths, H–K increases this quantity. When the shortest augmenting paths reach length √|V|, it's impossible to pack more than √|V| of them (vertex disjoint), so the algorithm has at most √|V| edges to go, and the total number of iterations is O(√|V|), for a O(|E| √|V|)-step running time.